# Given a python .pyc file, is there a tool that let me view the bytecode?

Tags: python, bytecode, pyc

A Python module is automatically compiled into a .pyc file by CPython interpreter. The .pyc file, which contains the bytecode, is in binary format (marshaled code?). Is there a GUI (or command line) tool that let me view the bytecode?

Comment: Are you fine with importing the module?  This would of course execute it.

Comment: Could you clarify "view the bytecode"?

Comment: do you want to decompile it to python code (`.py`) or to understand what each byte means?

Comment: I would like to look at and study the bytecode. I especially wants to find out how module global objects are represented.

Comment: Did a little google search and I found that Python comes with a module  called "dis" that let me do that. "import dis; import mymodule; dis.dis(module)". Still wondering if there is a GUI tool for this.

Comment: [python docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/dis.html#bytecodes) also list some bytecode meanings. Also, why do you want a GUI instead of python's prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a visual python disassembler called [PyChrisanthemum](http://code.google.com/p/pychrysanthemum/).

To do it the command-line way you can use module `dis` ([python 2.7.3](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html), [python 3.2.3](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/dis.html?highlight=dis#dis)), as OP already found out.

Comment: This project is now pretty dead, so I wouldn't expect it to be able to read (perfectly) the byte-code produced by recent Python versions.

Answer (score 15):

Every *.pyc file is a binary file containing next things:

- a four-byte magic number - it's simply bytes that change with each change to the marshalling code;
- a four-byte modification timestamp - is the Unix modification timestamp of the source file that generated the .pyc, so that it can be recompiled if the source changes;
- since version Python3.3+ next four bytes is field that encodes the size of the source file as a long;
- a marshalled code object.

Why not just use the CPython`s built-in features for this task?

---

A file `view_pyc_file.py`

```
import platform
import time
import sys
import binascii
import marshal
import dis
import struct


def view_pyc_file(path):
    """Read and display a content of the Python`s bytecode in a pyc-file."""

    file = open(path, 'rb')

    magic = file.read(4)
    timestamp = file.read(4)
    size = None

    if sys.version_info.major == 3 and sys.version_info.minor >= 3:
        size = file.read(4)
        size = struct.unpack('I', size)[0]

    code = marshal.load(file)

    magic = binascii.hexlify(magic).decode('utf-8')
    timestamp = time.asctime(time.localtime(struct.unpack('I', timestamp)[0]))

    dis.disassemble(code)

    print('-' * 80)
    print(
        'Python version: {}\nMagic code: {}\nTimestamp: {}\nSize: {}'
        .format(platform.python_version(), magic, timestamp, size)
    )

    file.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    view_pyc_file(sys.argv[1])
```

**Tested with next CPython`s versions:**

- 2.7.9
- 3.4.2
- 3.5.2

---

### Demonstration

Content of a file `main.py`

```
$ cat main.py
print("Never give up")
```

Create and to read pyc-file by the python2.7

```
setivolkylany$~/Downloads/temp/temp$ python2.7 -m py_compile main.py 
setivolkylany$~/Downloads/temp/temp$ python2.7 view_pyc_file.py ./main.pyc
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Never give up')
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE       
              5 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Python version: 2.7.9
Magic code: 03f30d0a
Timestamp: Fri Mar 10 15:08:20 2017
Size: None
```

Create and to read pyc-file by the python3.4

```
setivolkylany$~/Downloads/temp/temp$ python3.4 -m py_compile main.py 
setivolkylany$~/Downloads/temp/temp$ python3.4 view_pyc_file.py __pycache__/main.cpython-34.pyc 
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (print)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Never give up')
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
              9 POP_TOP
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Python version: 3.4.2
Magic code: ee0c0d0a
Timestamp: Fri Mar 10 15:08:20 2017
Size: 23
```

Create and to read pyc-file by the python3.5

```
setivolkylany$~/Downloads/temp/temp$ python3.5 -m py_compile main.py 
setivolkylany$~/Downloads/temp/temp$ python3.5 view_pyc_file.py __pycache__/main.cpython-35.pyc 
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (print)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Never give up')
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
              9 POP_TOP
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Python version: 3.5.2
Magic code: 160d0d0a
Timestamp: Fri Mar 10 15:08:20 2017
Size: 23
```

---

**Based on:**

- [How can I understand a .pyc file content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32562163/how-can-i-understand-a-pyc-file-content)
- https://gist.github.com/anonymous/35c08092a6eb70cdd723
- https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200804/the_structure_of_pyc_files.html

Comment: This now needs to be updated with regards to https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0552/ (Python 3.7).

Comment: I am unable to add the required modification here in the comments, so I've added it as a new answer, but @PADYMKO please feel free to edit your answer with it.

Answer (score 7):

Extending the code form @PADYMKO based on @Apteryx 's note about the PEP:

```py
def view_pyc_file(path):
    """Read and display a content of the Python`s bytecode in a pyc-file."""

    with open(path, 'rb') as file:

        magic = file.read(4)
        bit_field = None
        timestamp = None
        hashstr = None
        size = None

        if sys.version_info.major == 3 and sys.version_info.minor >= 7:
            bit_field = int.from_bytes(file.read(4), byteorder=sys.byteorder)
            if 1 & bit_field == 1:
                hashstr = file.read(8)
            else:
                timestamp = file.read(4)
                size = file.read(4)
                size = struct.unpack('I', size)[0]
        elif sys.version_info.major == 3 and sys.version_info.minor >= 3:
            timestamp = file.read(4)
            size = file.read(4)
            size = struct.unpack('I', size)[0]
        else:
            timestamp = file.read(4)

        code = marshal.load(file)

    magic = binascii.hexlify(magic).decode('utf-8')
    timestamp = time.asctime(time.localtime(struct.unpack('I', timestamp)[0]))

    dis.disassemble(code)

    print('-' * 80)
    print(
        'Python version: {}\nMagic code: {}\nTimestamp: {}\nSize: {}\nHash: {}\nBitfield: {}'
        .format(platform.python_version(), magic, timestamp, size, hashstr, bit_field)
    )
```

Comment: The only answer that works for Python 3.7! Thanks!