# How can I understand a .pyc file content

Tags: python, python-2.7, disassembly, pyc

I have a `.pyc` file. I need to understand the content of that file to know how the disassembler works of python, i.e. how can I generate a output like `dis.dis(function)` from `.pyc` file content.

for e.g.

```
>>> def sqr(x):  
...     return x*x
...
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(sqr)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

I need to get a output like this using the `.pyc` file.

Answer (score 28):

`.pyc` files contain some metadata and a [`marshal`ed](https://docs.python.org/2/library/marshal.html) `code` object; to load the `code` object and disassemble that use:

```
import dis, marshal, sys

header_sizes = [
    # (size, first version this applies to)
    # pyc files were introduced in 0.9.2 way, way back in June 1991.
    (8,  (0, 9, 2)),  # 2 bytes magic number, \r\n, 4 bytes UNIX timestamp
    (12, (3, 6)),     # added 4 bytes file size
    # bytes 4-8 are flags, meaning of 9-16 depends on what flags are set
    # bit 0 not set: 9-12 timestamp, 13-16 file size
    # bit 0 set: 9-16 file hash (SipHash-2-4, k0 = 4 bytes of the file, k1 = 0)
    (16, (3, 7)),     # inserted 4 bytes bit flag field at 4-8 
    # future version may add more bytes still, at which point we can extend
    # this table. It is correct for Python versions up to 3.9
]
header_size = next(s for s, v in reversed(header_sizes) if sys.version_info >= v)

with open(pycfile, "rb") as f:
    metadata = f.read(header_size)  # first header_size bytes are metadata
    code = marshal.load(f)          # rest is a marshalled code object

dis.dis(code)
```

Demo with the `bisect` module:

```
>>> import bisect
>>> import dis, marshal
>>> import sys
>>> header_sizes = [(8, (0, 9, 2)), (12, (3, 6)), (16, (3, 7))]
>>> header_size = next(s for s, v in reversed(header_sizes) if sys.version_info >= v)
>>> pycfile = getattr(bisect, '__cached__', pycfile.__file__)
>>> with open(pycfile, "rb") as f:
...     metadata = f.read(header_size)  # first header_size bytes are metadata
...     code = marshal.load(f)          # rest is bytecode
... 
>>> dis.dis(code)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Bisection algorithms.')
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (__doc__)

  3           4 LOAD_CONST              12 ((0, None))
              6 LOAD_CONST               3 (<code object insort_right at 0x10694f3a0, file "/.../lib/python3.8/bisect.py", line 3>)
              8 LOAD_CONST               4 ('insort_right')
             10 MAKE_FUNCTION            1 (defaults)
             12 STORE_NAME               1 (insort_right)

 15          14 LOAD_CONST              13 ((0, None))
             16 LOAD_CONST               5 (<code object bisect_right at 0x10694f2f0, file "/.../lib/python3.8/bisect.py", line 15>)
             18 LOAD_CONST               6 ('bisect_right')
             20 MAKE_FUNCTION            1 (defaults)
             22 STORE_NAME               2 (bisect_right)

 36          24 LOAD_CONST              14 ((0, None))
             26 LOAD_CONST               7 (<code object insort_left at 0x10694f240, file "/.../lib/python3.8/bisect.py", line 36>)
             28 LOAD_CONST               8 ('insort_left')
             30 MAKE_FUNCTION            1 (defaults)
             32 STORE_NAME               3 (insort_left)

 49          34 LOAD_CONST              15 ((0, None))
             36 LOAD_CONST               9 (<code object bisect_left at 0x10694f190, file "/.../lib/python3.8/bisect.py", line 49>)
             38 LOAD_CONST              10 ('bisect_left')
             40 MAKE_FUNCTION            1 (defaults)
             42 STORE_NAME               4 (bisect_left)

 71          44 SETUP_FINALLY           12 (to 58)

 72          46 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             48 LOAD_CONST              11 (('*',))
             50 IMPORT_NAME              5 (_bisect)
             52 IMPORT_STAR
             54 POP_BLOCK
             56 JUMP_FORWARD            20 (to 78)

 73     >>   58 DUP_TOP
             60 LOAD_NAME                6 (ImportError)
             62 COMPARE_OP              10 (exception match)
             64 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       76
             66 POP_TOP
             68 POP_TOP
             70 POP_TOP

 74          72 POP_EXCEPT
             74 JUMP_FORWARD             2 (to 78)
        >>   76 END_FINALLY

 77     >>   78 LOAD_NAME                2 (bisect_right)
             80 STORE_NAME               7 (bisect)

 78          82 LOAD_NAME                1 (insort_right)
             84 STORE_NAME               8 (insort)
             86 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             88 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object insort_right at 0x10694f3a0, file "/.../lib/python3.8/bisect.py", line 3>:
 12           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (bisect_right)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              4 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
              6 LOAD_FAST                2 (lo)
              8 LOAD_FAST                3 (hi)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            4
             12 STORE_FAST               2 (lo)

 13          14 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             16 LOAD_METHOD              1 (insert)
             18 LOAD_FAST                2 (lo)
             20 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             22 CALL_METHOD              2
             24 POP_TOP
             26 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object bisect_right at 0x10694f2f0, file "/.../lib/python3.8/bisect.py", line 15>:
 26           0 LOAD_FAST                2 (lo)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              4 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16

 27           8 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (ValueError)
             10 LOAD_CONST               2 ('lo must be non-negative')
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             14 RAISE_VARARGS            1

 28     >>   16 LOAD_FAST                3 (hi)
             18 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             20 COMPARE_OP               8 (is)
             22 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       32

 29          24 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (len)
             26 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             28 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             30 STORE_FAST               3 (hi)

 30     >>   32 LOAD_FAST                2 (lo)
             34 LOAD_FAST                3 (hi)
             36 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             38 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       80

 31          40 LOAD_FAST                2 (lo)
             42 LOAD_FAST                3 (hi)
             44 BINARY_ADD
             46 LOAD_CONST               4 (2)
             48 BINARY_FLOOR_DIVIDE
             50 STORE_FAST               4 (mid)

 32          52 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             54 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             56 LOAD_FAST                4 (mid)
             58 BINARY_SUBSCR
             60 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             62 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       70
             64 LOAD_FAST                4 (mid)
             66 STORE_FAST               3 (hi)
             68 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           32

 33     >>   70 LOAD_FAST                4 (mid)
             72 LOAD_CONST               5 (1)
             74 BINARY_ADD
             76 STORE_FAST               2 (lo)
             78 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           32

 34     >>   80 LOAD_FAST                2 (lo)
             82 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object insort_left at 0x10694f240, file "/.../lib/python3.8/bisect.py", line 36>:
 45           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (bisect_left)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              4 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
              6 LOAD_FAST                2 (lo)
              8 LOAD_FAST                3 (hi)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            4
             12 STORE_FAST               2 (lo)

 46          14 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             16 LOAD_METHOD              1 (insert)
             18 LOAD_FAST                2 (lo)
             20 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             22 CALL_METHOD              2
             24 POP_TOP
             26 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object bisect_left at 0x10694f190, file "/.../lib/python3.8/bisect.py", line 49>:
 60           0 LOAD_FAST                2 (lo)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              4 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16

 61           8 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (ValueError)
             10 LOAD_CONST               2 ('lo must be non-negative')
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             14 RAISE_VARARGS            1

 62     >>   16 LOAD_FAST                3 (hi)
             18 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             20 COMPARE_OP               8 (is)
             22 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       32

 63          24 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (len)
             26 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             28 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             30 STORE_FAST               3 (hi)

 64     >>   32 LOAD_FAST                2 (lo)
             34 LOAD_FAST                3 (hi)
             36 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             38 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       80

 65          40 LOAD_FAST                2 (lo)
             42 LOAD_FAST                3 (hi)
             44 BINARY_ADD
             46 LOAD_CONST               4 (2)
             48 BINARY_FLOOR_DIVIDE
             50 STORE_FAST               4 (mid)

 66          52 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             54 LOAD_FAST                4 (mid)
             56 BINARY_SUBSCR
             58 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             60 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             62 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       74
             64 LOAD_FAST                4 (mid)
             66 LOAD_CONST               5 (1)
             68 BINARY_ADD
             70 STORE_FAST               2 (lo)
             72 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           32

 67     >>   74 LOAD_FAST                4 (mid)
             76 STORE_FAST               3 (hi)
             78 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           32

 68     >>   80 LOAD_FAST                2 (lo)
             82 RETURN_VALUE(
```

Note that this is separates out the *top level code object*, defining the module, and the code objects of functions and classes. In Python 3.6 and older the `dis.dis()` function *won't recurse*. In those versions, if you wanted to analyse the functions contained, you'll need to load the nested `code` objects from the top-level `code.co_consts` array. For example, the `insort_right` function's code object is loaded with `LOAD_CONST 3`, so you look for the code object at that index:

```
>>> code.co_consts[3]
<code object insort_right at 0x10694f3a0, file "/.../lib/python3.8/bisect.py", line 3>
>>> dis.dis(code.co_consts[3])
 12           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (bisect_right)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              4 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
              6 LOAD_FAST                2 (lo)
              8 LOAD_FAST                3 (hi)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            4
             12 STORE_FAST               2 (lo)

 13          14 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             16 LOAD_METHOD              1 (insert)
             18 LOAD_FAST                2 (lo)
             20 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             22 CALL_METHOD              2
             24 POP_TOP
             26 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE
```

I personally would *avoid* trying to parse the `.pyc` file with anything other than the matching Python version and `marshal` module. The `marshal` format is basically an internal serialisation format that changes with the needs of Python itself. New features like list comprehensions and `with` statements and `async`/`await` require new additions to the format, which is not published other than as [C source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Python/marshal.c).

If you do go this route, and manage to [read a `code` object](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/02395fad8e3a35ef00fa31c308693844013a1dd4/Python/marshal.c#L1323-L1419) by other means than using the module, you'll have to parse out the disassembly from the various attributes of the code object; see the [`dis` module source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/dis.py) for details on how to do this (you'll have to use the `co_firstlineno` and `co_lnotab` attributes to create a bytecode-offset-to-linenumber map, for example).

Comment: There is a short blog post about the [`pyc file format`](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200804/the_structure_of_pyc_files.html). But I am sure to understand all of them completely you have to dive into the source of Python (which has a lot of good documentation in this area).