# Obfuscated Bytecode when uncompyling python pyc file

Tags: python, python-3.6, decompiling, pyc

I'm trying to decompile a pyc file with uncompyle6. The operation gives a Parse error at offset 966 as it says here.

```
Parse error at or near `POP_TOP' instruction at offset 996
```

Uncompyle prints the result of its decompiling and from that I can see the parse error is thrown after decompiling the last line of my code, which was root.mainloop() since the source code was a tkinter gui.

I'd appreciate it if someone could shed some light on how to fix bytecode to an absolute beginner and where I should begin. Since the error is thrown at the end of my code I feel like the error is rectifiable. 
Here's the error itself:

```
2295    6290  LOAD_NAME                'root'
        6292  LOAD_ATTR                'mainloop'
        6296  CALL_FUNCTION_0       0  ''
        6298  POP_TOP

Parse error at or near `POP_TOP' instruction at offset 996
```

Here's the bytecode around the error line

```
 966 LOAD_NAME               23 (ttk)
 968 LOAD_ATTR              110 (Button)
 970 LOAD_NAME              107 (iS1cols)
 972 LOAD_NAME              112 (tools_be_xl)
 974 LOAD_NAME               43 (tools_browse_xls)
 976 LOAD_CONST             126 (('textvariable', 'command'))
 978 CALL_FUNCTION_KW         3
 980 LOAD_ATTR              108 (grid)
 982 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
 984 LOAD_CONST             121 (20)
 986 LOAD_CONST             117 (4)
 988 LOAD_CONST             127 (2)
 990 LOAD_NAME              109 (W)
 992 LOAD_CONST             128 (('row', 'padx', 'pady', 'column', 'sticky'))
 994 CALL_FUNCTION_KW         5
 996 POP_TOP

 998 LOAD_NAME               23 (ttk)
1000 LOAD_ATTR              113 (LabelFrame)
1002 LOAD_NAME               91 (tab3Int)
1004 LOAD_CONST             129 (' Bulk Edit ')
1006 LOAD_CONST             107 (('text',))
1008 CALL_FUNCTION_KW         2
1010 STORE_NAME             114 (imgStep1)
```

Comment: Where does this bytecode come from? Also, I don't think `CALL_FUNCTION_0` is a instruction. What happens if you remove the `_0`?

Comment: it comes from a pyinstaller extractor. originally I had lost my source file due to corruption, and so I used a recent exe export from pyinstaller of the source code to reverse the executable back to my py source code. I now have that pyc file.

Comment: how could i remove it?

Comment: Never mind that last part, I misunderstood something. The error says it's at offset 966, not 6290. Can you show the code around that section?

Comment: I edited the question with more before the error. Yeah that difference was also peculiar to me

Comment: The error is near the line starting with 966. Can you show that section?

Comment: i've updated the question

Comment: I meant in the disassembly (the part displayed before the error). If it’s not displayed that far, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32562163/how-can-i-understand-a-pyc-file-content.

Comment: oh ok. i got what you mean. updated the question

Comment: Ok, try using the code from the answer to the question I linked, but add a `import inspect` at the top and replace the last line with `print("\n".join(inspect.getsourcelines(code)))`

Comment: I keep getting: OSError: source code not available. You mean to replace with which line exactly?

Comment: You replaced the correct line, but it seems like that approach won’t work. If you could put up a download for the .pyc, I’lol take a look.

Comment: thanks, https://www.dropbox.com/s/lwbyotxx5xy7u3c/templateg.pyc?dl=0

Comment: any chance my code can be recovered? I'm sorry to push it on you but I don't know what I can do to remedy this error. Is there maybe such a thing as a deobfuscator? I googled it but it seems you can only deobfuscate code that you've purposefuly obfuscated. I tried decompiling with pycdc but a) I don't know how to get it to work, b) it'll probably throw the same error...?

Comment: @internet_user see my answer for what's going on with `CALL_FUNCTION` vs `CALL_FUNCTION_0`

Answer (score 1):

Your program is thousands of lines long. After you whittle this down, into something smaller, report it at https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6/issues .

But note you'll probably need to put a fair bit of effort into whittling the program down into something tractable. If you don't want to spend the effort but instead want someone else to do the work for you, I've [listed a service that may be willing to do this](https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6/blob/master/HOW-TO-REPORT-A-BUG.md#but-i-dont-have-the-source-code-and-am-incapable-of-figuring-how-how-to-do-a-hand-disassembly). If there are other services that folks want me to list in that document, contact me.

I will say that in my experience *once a bug is whittled down*, except in the case of control flow bugs (and that doesn't appear to be relevant here) there often are small changes that then make even these huge files decompile properly.

There are two ways you could shorten the program for consideration of uncompyle6 bug fixing....

The easiest way is guessing the kind of code that causes the problem. Since you have some *idea* of where the problem is - you say it is in the last line of the tkinter gui loop -  write some new code that resembles that, byte compile that and see if decompiling that gives the same kind of error.

Perhaps you have some old source code with the same kind of tkinter gui loop. Try disassembling that. And then whittle that down so that it is no more than tens of lines long.

The second way is to use the `--asm` option on pydisasm found in the [xdis](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xdis) package. That will give you Python assembly code that can be more easily modified and that after doing so `pyc-xasm` of the [xasm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xasm) can turn back into a pyc file which you might be able to decompile.

However the `--xasm` option has some bugs in it that will take a while to shake down fully, so [use what's on github](https://github.com/rocky/python-xdis). Similarly uncompyle6 is in current upheaval in fixing Python 3.6 bugs which is relevant to your situation so [use what's on github](https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6) for that too

Now a little about what is no doubt an uncompyle6 bug. `POP_TOP` discards a value from the Python evaluation stack. This can occur for example when the return value of a call isn't used - perhaps the call is its own statement. However this kind of unused value happens all the time and uncompyle6 like most decompilers is happy with that. More likely, there is a nontrivial kind of call (with keyword arguments, * or ** calls) and Python  3.6 now creates bytecode that is very different from what it did in 3.5 or any other prior version.

*pycdc* will probably give an answer and it will probably give warnings with `Warning: block stack is not empty!`

Especially for *pycdc* on Python 3.6 be prepared to do a *lot* of fixing up, especially with respect to function definitions and function calls. You'll probably have to do likewise with uncompyle6 as well, but it is likely to be more semantically correct. So the fixing up is more about the way stuff is formatted.

uncompyle6 still has a ways to go when it comes to handling Python 3.6 as Python 3.6 drastically changed the semantics of stack entries in calling functions (as is probably the case here) and in creating functions. Even though Python 3.6 made a drastic change over 3.5, there is yet another drastic change in 3.7, so that will be a while before that is usable too. 
(See below with respect to ratings and how that relates to how much work I might spend on a project).

As for `CALL_FUNCTION` vs `CALL_FUNCTION_0`, this is an artifact of the way that uncompyle6 works. It uses a context-free grammar parser to build a parse tree of the program. Consequently, some information that is found as the operand of an instruction is sometimes added to the opcode, since parsing just works based on opcodes. This is described [here](https://github.com/rocky/python-xdis) and the bigger picture of how uncompyle6 works is described [here](http://rocky.github.io/Deparsing-Paper.pdf).

A final note, I use the rating (or stars) on github projects in deciding which projects to work when I have time to work on a project. The ratings for xasm, xdis are negligible which partially explains why you'll find bugs in them. (The other reason of course is a lack of time or the difficulty of the some of these projects).

Even uncompyle6 has pretty low ratings compared to other (largely abandoned) Python decompilers that haven't been worked on for a while and that don't do as good a job.