# How do I open a compiled python file (.pyc)

Tags: python-3.x, compilation

Lately I'm really interested in computer science and mainly in how do computers run our code.
I'm trying to see the content of my code after compiling my python program. If i try to open it it doesn't open or make weird symbols

I tried posting the code on 'pyc python extensions' online but they return **"We don't support this file format"**, and when trying to view on my computer it looks like random symbols

B

```
J~]y  ã               @   s   d dl Z dd„ ZdS )é    Nc              C   s<  t dƒ t dƒ t dƒ t dƒ t dƒ t dƒ xJtƒ } |  ¡ rpt| ƒ}|dkrZt dƒ qx|d  k rlt dƒ qxP q2t d
```

ƒ q2W d}|d  krŽd}n(|d
krœd}n|dkrªd}n|dkr¶d}t d    |¡}xttƒ }x.yt|ƒ}P W qÌ   t dƒ tƒ }Y qÌX qÌW ||krt dƒ P qÄ||kr$t dƒ qÄ||k rÄt dƒ qÄW d S )NzWelcome to GUESS THAT NUMBERzPick your level:z    1) Amateur   (0-10)z    2) Enthusiast (0-30)z    3) Advanced    (0-70)z    4) Expert     (0-100)é   z!Pick a VALID level!é   zPick a DEFINED unitr   é   é   é   é   éG   ée   zPlease enter a NUMBERz GREAT JOBzA Lower Number...zA Higher Number...)ÚprintÚinputÚisdigitÚintÚrandomÚrandint)ZchoiseÚchZnum01ÚxÚeÚy© r   ú5C:/Users/Tomerinio/Documents/#TB/Python\EraseLater.pyÚplayGame   sT

r   )r   r   r   r   r   r   Ú   s

EDIT: The site doesn't show it but through out the code above there are a lot of "randomly" place squares that loo like '❏' without the shading.

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32562163/how-can-i-understand-a-pyc-file-content ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to see what goes into .pyc files is to disassemble a python function

```py
import dis

def f():
    x = 1
    a = x
    print(a, x)

dis.dis(f)
```

and the output should look something like this

```
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  3           4 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (a)

  4           8 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
             10 LOAD_FAST                1 (a)
             12 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             16 POP_TOP
             18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

Every operation you see here (`LOAD_CONST`, `STORE_FAST` etc.) has an associated operation code (opcode), also known as bytecode. Each bytecode is stored in its binary form in the .pyc file, alongside the "lists" of constants, variables, functions, etc.

It's more to explain to bytecodes, but if you're really interested how it works, there are plenty good articles online about them. In the meantime you can check [this](https://opensource.com/article/18/4/introduction-python-bytecode) one.

If you have understood them and liked the matter, you can try learning [assembly language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you're trying to execute a `.pyc` file as if it were an actual program.

A `.pyc` file is not an executable, it is Python bytecode meant to be ran by the Python interpreter. It compiles scripts to this before running them.

If you'd like to disassemble the Python bytecode, try the `dis` module.

```
>>> import helloworld
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(helloworld)
Disassembly of main:
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Hello, world!')
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 POP_TOP
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE

>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

When we generate our compiled code of any pyhton file that has a extension (.pyc) which is actually the bytecode of our code.

But if we try to open that bytecode , we cannot able to open that because our machine don't have such software which supports that type or format of file.

But there is some alternate way to see the bytecode in readable format. Although bytecode is actually a intermediate langauge in itself which is not directly understandable to machine or not even to programmer.

Steps are :-

1. Open cmd and navigate to the folder where you saved your pyhton file
2. Write command
   pyhton -m dis

here -m is called switch which is used add extra information for pyhton.
The dis command is known as “disassembler” that displays the byte code in an understandable format.

The code represents 5 columns:

1-Line Number
2-offset position of byte code
3-name of byte code instruction
4-instruction’s argument
5-constants or names (in brackets)

Thank you!! Hope this thing will help you