# Python 3 bytecode format

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, bytecode

I want to read a `.pyc` file. However, I cannot find any documentation on the format.

The [only one I found](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200804/the_structure_of_pyc_files.html) does not work for Python 3 (although it does for Python 2):

```
>>> f = open('__pycache__/foo.cpython-34.pyc', 'rb')
>>> f.read(4)
b'\xee\x0c\r\n'
>>> f.read(4)
b'\xf8\x17\x08W'
>>> marshal.load(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

marshal only consumes one byte: `\x00`, which indeed is not a valid first character for marshall (as a comparison, the first byte of Python 2 bytecode for the same empty module is `c`)

So, how can I decode what comes after the header?

Comment: From version Pytho3.3+ you need read not 8 first bytes, but 12. Read my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/42720524/6003870

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. It worked a while back. They added another int32 in v3.

```
def load_file(self, source):
    if isinstance(source, str):
        import os.path
        if not os.path.exists(source):
            raise IOError("Cannot load_file('"
                + source
                + "'): does not exist")
        with open(source, "rb") as fh:
            header_bytes = fh.read(12)
            # ignore header
            self.code = marshal.load(fh)

        return self.code
```

Comment: This seems as if it should be a normal function (without `self`).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the dissembler?
https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html

Comment: The disassembler takes a code object, which must be decoded (the resource I linked uses marshal for that)