# Python get optcodes from .pyc files

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtual-machine, bytecode

I am currently implementing a Python interpreter in Rust. Basically, I want it be able to run python compiled code, in a *.pyc* file. I will write the compiler is a separate project.

I am having huge trouble mapping the bytecode on the *.pyc* file to the corresponding optcode. Here is an example:

The original file, **hello_world.py**

```py
def hello():
    print("Hello World")
```

I compile this file into *.pyc* by using the command:

```sh
python3 -m compileall hello_world.py
```

I know that I can get the optcode mapping using the [dis modudle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.opmap), so my idea was to just read the *.pyc* file as a u8 vector in rust and then map the bytes. However, here is my problem. If I dissassemble the original python file with the dis module I get this:

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object hello at 0x7f4a42392240, file "hello_world.py", line 1>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('hello')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (hello)
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object hello at 0x7f4a42392240, file "hello_world.py", line 1>:
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Hello World')
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 POP_TOP
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

But, if I do the hexdump, with the -C flag, on the *.pyc* file, I get this:

```
00000000  55 0d 0d 0a 00 00 00 00  bc 91 40 62 25 00 00 00  |U.........@b%...|
00000010  e3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 02 00 00 00 40 00 00  00 73 0c 00 00 00 64 00  |.....@...s....d.|
00000030  64 01 84 00 5a 00 64 02  53 00 29 03 63 00 00 00  |d...Z.d.S.).c...|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00  |................|
00000050  00 43 00 00 00 73 0c 00  00 00 74 00 64 01 83 01  |.C...s....t.d...|
00000060  01 00 64 00 53 00 29 02  4e 7a 0b 48 65 6c 6c 6f  |..d.S.).Nz.Hello|
00000070  20 57 6f 72 6c 64 29 01  da 05 70 72 69 6e 74 a9  | World)...print.|
00000080  00 72 02 00 00 00 72 02  00 00 00 fa 0e 68 65 6c  |.r....r......hel|
00000090  6c 6f 5f 77 6f 72 6c 64  2e 70 79 da 05 68 65 6c  |lo_world.py..hel|
000000a0  6c 6f 01 00 00 00 73 02  00 00 00 00 01 72 04 00  |lo....s......r..|
000000b0  00 00 4e 29 01 72 04 00  00 00 72 02 00 00 00 72  |..N).r....r....r|
000000c0  02 00 00 00 72 02 00 00  00 72 03 00 00 00 da 08  |....r....r......|
000000d0  3c 6d 6f 64 75 6c 65 3e  01 00 00 00 f3 00 00 00  |<module>........|
000000e0  00                                                |.|
000000e1
```

the dis module disassembler tells me that this code has 12 optcode instructions, so I as expecting the *.pyc* file to have 12 * 2 bytes (Because it's two bytes per optcode). However, it seems that the *.pyc* file has 200+ bytes, and that is making me really confused.

How can I manage to get the optcodes from the *.pyc* file, without using the python modules?

Thank you!

Comment: Related: [Given a python .pyc file, is there a tool that let me view the bytecode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11141387/11082165), [How can I understand a .pyc file content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32562163/11082165)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I understand a .pyc file content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32562163/how-can-i-understand-a-pyc-file-content). [Martjin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32562303/11082165) still works as of Python 3.8.

Comment: Yes it seems that it does. Thank you, don't know how I missed this. Will read it more carefully in a moment just to be sure, but it seems that it has the information that I want!

Comment: As a summary for future users, .pyc files have 12-16 bytes storing the version number and timestamp, and then a marshalled CodeObject which stores the code.